# Cannot test onInstall on test deployment in google sheet scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My `onOpen` for showing custom menu in google sheet scripts is working perfectly and I have also done `onInstall` simply like this

```
function onInstall(e){
   onOpen(e)
}
```

onOpen is running under all oath types but then google give this error when I try to publish addon

> Menu - Menu options not shown after App is installed. Please ensure that the add-on correctly uses onInstall() and onOpen() to populate its menu. The menu items populate when the add-on is first installed and when a different file is opened. See Editor add-on authorization.

So I don't understand this problem also if anyone know how to mock onInstall please let me know.

I tried running test deployment but cannot mock onInstall in it.

Comment: I was also unable to test `onInstall` with test deployments. According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installing) it runs when it's installed *from the store*, which means you'd have to publish the app internally on a Google Workspace domain, which doesn't require verification. Then you can test installing it from the internal store. Aside from that I'm not aware of other workarounds.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for your answer. But we need verification for publically publish the addon, maybe you tried to deploy privately/for your domain only?

Comment: I mean, you can try to deploy it internally to test your trigger, then when you're certain that it works you can try to publish it again. With just your code sample it's impossible to tell why exactly they rejected it, since there's nothing really *wrong* with it, but more context is needed.

Comment: Yeah working this way thanks @Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution as Daniel mentioned.

First private deploy and test the extention then it should work when extention will be deployed publically. Otherwise we can't test onInstall.